# How to check if a specific value exists between values in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For example I have an array `['15, Balloons', '1, Onions', '18, Soap']`

How do I check if the word "Soap" is in any of the options, ignoring the other value ("18," in this case)?

I've tried using `include?` but `include?` only returns boolean if the whole `18, Soap` is there

Comment: _"ignoring the other value"_ – `'18, Soap'` is _one_ value, not two. You might want to split the values and use a two-dimensional array instead, e.g. `[[15, 'Balloons'], [1, 'Onions'], [18, 'Soap']]` and use `ary.any? { |n, s| s == 'Soap' }`

Comment: You need to specify what you actually **mean** by _the other value_. For example, what happens if the entry is `'This is my Soap'`, or `'Soapbox'`. or `'18 Soaps'`. Do these contain `Soap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's check if any of the array's items include `Soap`

```
soap_present = arr.any? { |item| item.include?('Soap') }
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this would also locate an item named `Soapbox`. Whether this is or isn't what the OP wanted, I don't know.

Comment: good point @user1934428 thank you